# Call <div> element with special character "-"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax

I'm new with javascript and jquery. I'm trying to use the following code to change the value of the div element "data-transitiongoal", but the special character is breaking my code. Could you please help me with the syntax??

This is not working:

```
document.getElementById("performance1").data-transitiongoal= "80";
```

My div element is this one:

div id="performance1" class="progress-bar bg-green" role="progressbar" data-transitiongoal="40"

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look at the `dataset` property.

Comment: Excelent! I looked at it and its working perfectly. Thank you so much for your quick help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value of an HTML element using JavaScript, for properties like `border-radius` that are more than one word, you would write the property in camel case. Maybe try this:

```
document.getElementById("performance1").dataTransitiongoal= "80";
```

You can also try using jQuery:

```
$("#performance1").attr('data-transitiongoal', 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery data method will work also:

```
$("#performance1").data('transitiongoal', 80);
```

to change the data value of the div. If you want to change the content of the div, that's something different entirely.